# GDAL grid Not recognizing csv as having geometry

Tags: python, gdal, interpolation, gdal-grid

**NON-DUPLICATE EDIT:** This question is not a duplicate because I have tried the solution presented as the answer to the "original" question and it did not work. See results below.

I am attempting to use `gdal.Grid` in python to interpolate a .txt or .csv to a raster. I keep getting `"ERROR 1: Failed to open datasource 'file.csv'. No point geometry found on layer file, skipping."`

How do I get `gdal.Grid` to recognize the file? Or how do I need to alter the file in order to get gdal to recognize it?

**EDIT:** Ran ogrinfo twice, both with txt and csv versions. The results were the same each time, with the only difference being the extensions each time matched what was in the vrt and what the file was. ___Stupid question, if a text file is structured like a csv you can usually just change the extension to csv and programs will handle it, I've been doing that when "changing format", could this be part of the issue?

Below, column 1 is x, column 2 is y, column 3 is z but they do not have headers.

**Data file structure:**

```
555000,66600,001
555003,66610,002
555002,66601,003
```

**VRT file**

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="file">
        <SrcDataSource>CSV:file.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

**Relavant python code**

```
rasname = str(file)
rasname = rasname.split('\\')
rasname = rasname[-1]
rasname = rasname.strip('.txt')
vrtname = rasname + '.vrt'
vrtname = input_dir + '\\' + vrtname

outputfile = output_dir + str(rasname) + '.tif'


gridopt = gdal.GridOptions(format='GTiff',algorithm='invdist:power=2')

output = gdal.Grid(outputfile, vrtname, options=gridopt)
```

**Results of ogrinfo**

```
INFO: Open of 'file.vrt' using driver 'OGR_VRT' successful.
Warning 1: Cannot open datasource 'file.csv' in update mode. Trying again in read-only mode
Error 1: Failed to open datasource 'file.csv'

Layer name: file
Geometry: None
Feature Coutn: 0
Layer SRS WKT: 
(unknown)
```

Comment: Use `<SrcDataSource>CSV:file.txt</SrcDataSource>` to fix it.

Comment: @ Luke, I've tried using changing the name/format from txt to csv. Both have resulted in either .csv or .txt error. I've made sure the VRT matches when I make the change.

Comment: @Mike T I attempted this just now, I receive the same error.

Comment: What version of GDAL?

Comment: 2.2.4 in python 3.7

Comment: @Mike T I run all my python via batch files.

Comment: Could it be about encoding of text file? Encoding of txt/csv file may have to be UTF-8.

Comment: @Luke made the update.

Comment: @Luke It won't open in Excel/Calc. It's too big. I've opened it in liquid studio. Which opens it like a textfile.

Comment: What is the file size? Do you know how many rows there are in the file?

Comment: @Kadir files size is approx 7GB. Rows being I believe around 500 million.

Comment: @Luke I'm on windows. File ends with a complete row and then a new empty row. No commas in last row. no spaces. just a new blank row.

Comment: @Luke I am unable to get that to work. I get Select-Object Cabbit bind parrameter last. Cannot convert value "output.txt" to type "System.Int32". Error "input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: @Luke NVM, got working. it's parsing the csv.

Comment: If it works write an answer so that your solution may help other people as well.

Comment: @Luke, Sorry, I see how that could have been confusing. Powershell was working. The last few lines are all complete entries of xyz coordinates.